# Header logo way to big on my TwentyEleven Wordpress theme

Tags: css, header

I have been trying to adjust my site's header logo size as now its way to big. I would like it to by 476 x 83px (which is the files nominal size) and tried tweaking the functions.php and style.css but can't seem to figure out why my header image remains so big and stretched.

I tried changing the values in the code below in the corresponding part of the style.css script but it has no effect on the size. Not sure where or how to control this on my site.

```
#branding img {
height: auto;
display: block;
```

The site I am working with is https://divesummit.com

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. you are adding too large value to the logo width and height
   normal sizes are **250 x 100px**

   2 while you are trying **476px** for width which is a too-large size and only **83** for height which is not equal to the normal logo and looks too small.

   try this code

"

```
#branding img{
height: 100px;
    width: 250px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}"
```